# Add react component in iframe in an angular application

Tags: reactjs, angular, iframe

I'm looking for a solution to **embed a react library inside my angular** 13 application

My angular app needs to have a react component loaded... But the setting of this component is only possible based on the URL...
A solution could be to use an iframe, but I do not know how to do the implementation, even if it is possible.

I already try to create a component *iframe.component.ts* with

```
import {
  AfterViewInit,
  Component,
  ComponentFactoryResolver,
  ComponentRef, ElementRef, OnDestroy,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild,
  ViewContainerRef
} from "@angular/core";
import {reactComponent} from "./react-stuff.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'iframe-react',
  templateUrl: 'iframe.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['']
})
export class IframeComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('compFrame', {static: false}) CompFrame: ElementRef | undefined;
  doc: any;
  compRef: ComponentRef<reactComponent> | undefined;

  constructor(private VcRef: ViewContainerRef, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {
    super()
  }

  public onLoad(){
    this.doc = this.CompFrame?.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.CompFrame?.nativeElement.CompFrame.contentWindow;
    this.createComponent();
  }

  private createComponent():void{
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(reactComponent);
    this.compRef = this.VcRef.createComponent(compFactory);
    this.compRef.location.nativeElement.id = 'propertyDisplay';
    this.doc.body.appendChild(this.compRef.location.nativeElement);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit():void{
    this.onLoad();
  }

}
```

With this kind of template:

```
<section class="shell">
  <iframe class="iframeShell" #compFrame></iframe>
</section>
```

But the result is empty... I can see the iframe, but there is no content and no error message in the console:
[image]